# How to redirect in nestjs Application other than res.redirect

Tags: node.js, nestjs

I want to redirect to a website(in NestJs Application) but using the res() from express is not applicable for me

```
import { Response } from 'express';

  @Get('qrmenu/business/:id')
  public async ResponseToQRScan(@Param() params: IdValidator, @Res() res: Response,
@Query() qrQuery: QrScanQueryDto): Promise<any> {
console.log(qrQuery)
if (qrQuery.app !== true || !qrQuery.app) {
  return res.redirect(`https://masovison.com/about/`)
}
let menu = await this.menuService.getMenuOfABusiness(params.id);
// console.log(menu)
res.send({ menu })
```

}

PS: The Redirect is a conditional situation so controller should either redirect to a website or send the response as per condition.

*is there any other way that I can redirect to a website in NestJS application ?*

Answer (score 1):

You would either use the `@Redirect()` decorator or call `res.redirect()` directly as stated [here](https://docs.nestjs.com/controllers#redirection). And also:

> Returned values will override any arguments passed to the `@Redirect()` decorator. For example:
>
> ```
> @Get('docs')
> @Redirect('https://docs.nestjs.com', 302)
> getDocs(@Query('version') version) {
>   if (version && version === '5') {
>     return { url: 'https://docs.nestjs.com/v5/' };
>   }
> }
> ```

Comment: I want send the response data if app=true and redirect to website if not but using redirect decorator will alway redirect no matter what can you help it to make optional?

Comment: I guess you have to use `res.redirect` then.

Comment: I was searching for the alternatives for that since it ruins the response interceptor of the app